# Toolbar with four icons how can set like this image?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Toolbar with four icons how can set like this image ?

I want to set four icons like image in toolbar.

i have make toolbar . & setting icons in menu_main.xml .But i am not getting .Why could any one help me why it is not coming ?

[image]

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#f26925"

       >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <!--<TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mumbai"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />-->
    <!-- Layout for content is here. This can be a RelativeLayout  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Profile">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/loc"
        android:icon="@drawable/loc"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Profile">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Profile">
    </item>
</menu>
```

After using this i am not getting icons in toolbar. no icon is appearing why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add menu inflating code inside your Activity
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use customize view for toolbar

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.actionbar_customview, null);

    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.action_appicon);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

actionbar_customview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="left">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/upgrade"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="11dp"
    android:textColor="#c23c3c"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/upgrade"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/upgrade_button_round"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/noticication_icn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/notificationID"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notificationsCount"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/textviewcircle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ppp_icn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/projectCoordinate"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what is "content_main" ? I am getting error getSupportActionBar  can not resolved

Comment: ActionBarActivity has been deprecated so please use the following

        public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

ignore content_main  it is jst my layout which is appended