# Unable to set icons in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Unable to set icons in toolbar ? How can i set four icons in toolbar?

Please see in the image i have to set like this image .

[image]

But i am not getting like this image . I am getting title which i don't want . icons are not coming exactly as i want . Please see the code tell me where i can make necessary changes?

toolbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#f26925"     >


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/loc"
            android:contentDescription="@string/loc"
            android:src="@drawable/loc" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/loc"
            android:id="@+id/bookmark"
            android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bookmark"

            android:src="@drawable/search" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

By using this i am getting like this image . I don't want this title and want exactly first image .

what are changes required for same please tell me ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't [repeat questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865342/toolbar-with-four-icons-how-can-set-like-this-image). Simply editing your original post with any new information you have will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: not repeating question .earlier was different i was not getting icons . In this i am getting icons but not proper alignment . Please read question proper . Hope you will cooperate .

Comment: Both questions are "How do I make my toolbar look like this picture?" They are the same question, with the same XML, and with the exact same image. You should've just edited your previous question to explain why the offered solutions didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this and adjust your layout according to your need.Please be careful my answer is not exactly what you want but an example so that you can achieve your desired view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#f26925"

       >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner_alt"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetwo" />
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/banner_alt"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetwo" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes i used this But not proper padding there You can see i have attached image and code after changes .how can i  set proper spacing between icons ?

Comment: @user6313669 you can use weight, Anyway u can do same way as if you have to set in android layout

Comment: I have used but not getting .

Comment: @user6313669 Please learn how set layout in linearlayout and relative layout Refer here: http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-linearlayout/      http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-relativelayout/